# Django build Models with duplicating data is a correct way?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I'm new to Django. But have a doubt now regarding building Models within one Django app with certain relations.

For example I have an `accounts` app with defined model `User(AbstractUser)` which works fine. I've created a new Django app `records` with a model `Bill` which suppose to handle a certain service records with following fields:

- year_due
- service_name
- cost

To link `User` with a `Bill` I've created an additional model `Payment` which contains:

- user_id
- bill_id
- service_name
- year_due

Is this example a good practice to define models or better to incapsulate such a fields within one class?
I want to make it clear to see the relevant data. The main idea is to clearly see to which `service_name` a certain `bill` or `payment` belong.

The raw example of my code I haven't yet migrate:

```
class Bill(models.Model):
    service_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    fixed_cost = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=True, blank=True)
    current_counter = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    consumption = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    cost_per_unit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    payed_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    is_paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Payment(models.Model):
    bill_id = models.ForeignKey(Bill, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    record_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    service_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    year_due = models.IntegerField()
    month_due = models.IntegerField()
    payed_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
```

Thank You in advance for any feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general this is a database structure or data structure question - not a django implementation question.
I would assume that first there is a User ... then Bill for a service .... then a Payment for a Bill.

As the Bill defines the service, there should not be a second service definition in Payment.

You can always access the service_name via payment.bill_id.service_name

It seems also strange to me that a payment has a due date. Due date should be part of a Bill and can be a DateField.

```
class Bill(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    service_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    payment_due = models.DateField()
    #.....
    fixed_cost = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=True, blank=True)
    current_counter = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    consumption = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    cost_per_unit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    payed_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    is_paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Payment(models.Model):
    bill_id = models.ForeignKey(Bill, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # .....
    record_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    payed_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
```

Comment: Thank You for a quick response. Agree that question more relates to Database topics, therefore want to apologize that I've missed that fact. Regarding "due_date" field is that convenient later on to search by year or just for a certain month if I have complete DateField in one cell? Isn't more conviniet to have a year or month as separate value as Integer? I might be wrong, so just questioning )

Comment: the point with DateField field is e.g. django built-in validation of form input data can check for months between 1..12 .. as Integer you would have to program validation etc. all by hand. You can also search more easy in date range etc. And if needed you can access month and year fields of DateField like Payment.objects.filter(record_date__month=11). see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#month or in general field lookups https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups

Comment: Thank You once again for clear answer. It sounds good